# Could not find artifact (snapshot) in Nexus repository

Tags: java, docker, maven, nexus, snapshot

I installed the Nexus repository in my notebook, then upload a snapshot project in it. This is how it looks:

[image]

Now, I'm trying to build a Docker image, with another project that has the previous project as a dependency. This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM maven:3.5.2-jdk-8-alpine AS MAVEN_BUILD
COPY settings.xml /usr/share/maven/ref/
COPY pom.xml /build/
RUN echo $(route -n | awk '/UG[ \t]/{print $2}')
RUN sed -i "s/localhost/$(route -n | awk '/UG[ \t]/{print $2}')/g" /build/pom.xml
COPY src /build/src/
WORKDIR /build/
RUN mvn package -DskipTests=true

# Other stuff that doesn't matter...
```

I've added this lines to pom.xml to resolve dependencies from Nexus (locahost is replaced (see Dockerfile) with docker gateway IP):

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>maven-group</id>
        <url>http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-group/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

It works as expected until maven needs to dowload my own library dependecy, the one uploaded to Nexus, failing with the message:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project springboot-servicio-producto: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.abarazal.springboot.app.producto:springboot-servicio-producto:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.abarazal.springboot.app.commons:springboot-servicio-commons:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT in maven-group (http://172.17.0.1:8081/repository/maven-group/) -> [Help 1]
```

In pom.xml the dependency is declared as:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.abarazal.springboot.app.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>springboot-servicio-commons</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

What am I missing to make it work?

Comment: I have exacly the same issue. Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I copied the dependency tags which are under the usage tab.

As shown in the usage copy the dependency from there which is (in your case),

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.abarazal.sringboot.app.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>springboot-servicio-commons</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1.20200017.2123240</version>
</dependency>
```

Then reload the pom.

Answer (score -1):

Check if you have more than 10% free disk space.
This may be an issue caused by elastic search.